# How to add query params to URL in API in WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to append query params to endpoint URI according to query params in  request.

I have an resource API in ESB published like this:

```
<resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/searchEngine/sortAndFilterVolunteers*">
  <inSequence>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <address
                uri="http://localhost:8080/project-web-services/services/project-rs"></address>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
```

I have to append query params dinamically.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Following sample API definition may help you.

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sample" context="/api/sample">
   <resource methods="OPTIONS GET" uri-template="/{val1}/groups/{val2}.json?q1={v1}&q2={v2}">
  <inSequence>
     <property name="uri.var.q1" expression="$url:q1"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.q2" expression="$url:q2"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.val1" expression="get-property('uri.var.val1')"></property>
     <property name="uri.var.val2" expression="get-property('uri.var.val2')"></property>
     <send>
        <endpoint>
           <http method="GET" uri-template=""></http>
        </endpoint>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send></send>
  </outSequence>
  </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: My problem is that the URL is different each time. For example, a request may be http://server:port/service?q1={q1} and other request may be http://server:port/service?q2={q2}&q3={q3}.

This is because they are optional, and need to do the mapping according to those arriving params with the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add the query parameter to uri-template in resource as below :

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/getStudents/{id}">
```

When sending to the endpoint,

```
<send>
    <endpoint>
        <http method="get" uri-template="http://studentsapi/student/{uri.var.id}"/>
    </endpoint>
</send>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the query parameter to url-mapping in resource as below : url-mapping="/*"

### *

you can send a request may be server:port/service?q1={q1} and other request may be server:port/service?q2={q2}&q3={q3}.